# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSBJSON", referenced from: objc-class-ref in FacebookController.o

Tags: ios, facebook

I just download new facebook ios sdk.
It reports error when build,

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F"/Users/myname/cd-standard/apple/apple_ios/Projects/fotoshow_ios/my app/../../../../../../Documents/FacebookSDK"'
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSBJSON", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FacebookController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

the prohect with former facebook ios sdk works well, I only install the new ios sdk using downloaded installer.

I also check and find out all frameworks needed are there, but it still reports error

[image]

[image]

[image]

your comment welcome

Comment: I think FacebookSDK.framework needs to be copied in documents directory, have you done that?

See relevant sections here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FBSBJSON was removed in v3.5 of the Facebook SDK (released April 18, 2013), but your FacebookController class is still referencing it. You should remove the reference in your FacebookController class, or if you're using some other SDK which wraps the Facebook SDK, you'll probably need to update that as well.